# Dropping columns based on the column number - SAS

Tags: sql, sas, relational-database

I have a dataset containing the following columns:

```
ID, value, value1, value2
```

I want to keep columns `ID` and `value`. I want to drop the rest based on numerical position. So `value1` and `value2` are equivalent to 3 and 4. I want to drop anything greater than or equal to 3.

Is there any syntax in the SAS/SQL repertoire that will allow me to reference and drop the columns based on their position.

```
DATA TEST;
   INPUT id $ value value1 value2;
   DATALINES;
a 10 1 8
a 13 2 11
a 14 3 23
b 15 4 44
b 44 5 45
c 64 6 67
c 32 6 47
d 12 7 895
;
RUN;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to read the columns from `sashelp.vcolumn`, then save the first 4 columns into a macro variable.

```
proc sql inobs=4;
    select name
    into :keepcols separated by ','
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = 'WORK'
          AND memname = 'TEST';

proc sql;
    select &keepcols
    from TEST;
quit;
```

If you cannot use the dictionary table for some reason, you can use `proc transpose` to get the columns:

```
proc transpose data=TEST(obs=0)
               out=cols;
run;

proc sql noprint inobs=4;
    select _NAME_
    into :keepcols separated by ','
    from cols;
quit;

proc sql;
    select &keepcols
    from TEST;
quit;
```

Comment: Stu - I appreciate the response. I'm not familiar with the sample data you provide, however. Could you do it with the mock data I've appended to my question? Sorry, should have just provided it in the first place.

Comment: I have changed it to use your dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Proc Contents is often quicker to execute than the dictionary tables.

```
PROC CONTENTS DATA=sourcetable OUT=temptable NOPRINT ;
RUN ;

PROC SQL ;

  SELECT name
    INTO :selectclause SEPARATED BY ', '
    FROM temptable
    WHERE varnum LE 3
    ORDER BY npos
  ;

  CREATE TABLE shorttable AS
    SELECT &selectclause
      FROM sourcetable
  ;

QUIT ;
```

Comment: I think you mean varnum LE 3 instead of npos LE 3.  Varnum is the logical variable number (order).

Comment: YES!  Thanks!  Edit made.